# Use specific "col sep=&" with \pgfplotstableread{⟨file name⟩}{⟨\macro⟩}

Tags: pgfplotstable

I would like to make one table that consist of data (Columns) from multiple (7) input files. I know for a pgfplot this can be done by simply loading data from different sources into one graph. I have however not been able to transfer this method to tables.

Instead I was intending to load all the data using `\pgfplotstableread{⟨file name⟩}{⟨\macro⟩}` and then add the columns via the macros as described in the manual.

The problem with this approach however is that I could not figure out how to specify any of the source file formatting.

- header=false
- col sep=&

Is there a way to do this?

What I got thus far:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

% Usepackages
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx, ragged2e} % CC
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % linksbündig mit Breitenangabe
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % zentriert mit Breitenangabe
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % rechtsbündig mit Breitenangabe

% Path definitions
\newcommand{\CCData}{../../Data/CC}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{\CCData/results/1318AaBb-1day.txt}{\AfAaBbA}
\pgfplotstableread{\CCData/results/1318AaBb-2day.txt}{\AfAaBbB}

% missing part but I don't even get to load the to fiels

\end{document}
```

If I compile this I get the following error:

```
./1318AaBb-1day.tex:21: Package pgfplots Error: Table '../../Data/CC/results/13
18AaBb-1day.txt' appears to have too many columns in line 11: Ignoring 'Sebasti
an&2&2&22&2&1&21&1909.3125&1773.2791666666667&0.34166666666666501&135.691666666
66658&694.02916666666647&36.187499999999986&292.95416666666659&364.887499999999
93&365&224&42&99&1743'. PGFPlots found that the number of columns is larger tha
n the previously determined number of columns. Please verify that every cell en
try is separated correctly (use braces {<cell entry>} if necessary. Also verify
 that column names are plain ASCII.). This error is not critical.

See the pgfplots package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.21 ...CData/results/1318AaBb-1day.txt}{\AfAaBbA}
                                              ^^M
?
```

Loading the first file directly with `\pgfplotstabletypeset[options]{\CCData/results/1318AaBb-1day.txt}` does however work.

Here the first 13 rows of my input file:

```
001. Porto, Portugal &Portugal&Porto&4&2&42&4&1&41&1491.6666666666674&1291.7916666666674&2.4958333333333336&197.37916666666663&882.76250000000005&31.149999999999991&485.70416666666665&365.90833333333336&365&184&69&112&2106
002. Braganca, Portugal &Portugal&Bragança&2&1&21&2&1&21&2339.974999999999&2207.4624999999992&0.28333333333333854&132.22916666666671&893.21249999999998&13.983333333333352&700.82083333333333&178.40833333333333&365&222&81&62&152
003. Coimbra, Portugal &Portugal&Coimbra&4&2&42&4&2&42&1294.3124999999998&1155.1208333333332&3.6291666666666664&135.5625&1209.1083333333333&27.895833333333329&943.25416666666672&237.95833333333326&365&166&125&74&2532
004. Lisbon, Portugal &Portugal&Lisbon&4&2&42&4&2&42&1086.0833333333335&964.28333333333353&2.3333333333333393&119.46666666666668&1443.9624999999996&21.954166666666637&1219.7791666666662&202.22916666666666&365&151&150&64&2394
005. La Coruna, Spain &Spain&La Coruña&4&2&42&4&1&41&1487.9537500000001&1360.1995833333335&0&127.75416666666669&764.72916666666674&58.320833333333283&269.34999999999997&437.05833333333351&365&214&41&110&1613
006. Pontevedra, Spain &Spain&Pontevedra&4&1&41&4&1&41&1328.2791666666665&1212.5999999999999&0&115.67916666666666&1062.6833333333332&50.558333333333323&598.98749999999984&413.1375000000001&365&186&77&102&709
007. Lugo, Spain &Spain&Lugo&2&1&21&1&1&11&2496.2333333333318&2317.1583333333315&3.2666666666666622&175.80833333333331&446.71666666666658&11.90833333333334&140.33333333333337&294.47499999999991&365&247&24&94&320
008. Oviedo, Spain &Spain&Oviedo&2&1&21&1&1&11&2018.7999999999986&1882.108333333332&0&136.69166666666666&587.9041666666667&30.062499999999986&247.41250000000002&310.42916666666667&365&237&39&89&958
009. Santander, Spain &Spain&Santander&4&2&42&4&2&42&1368.9958333333332&1270.2249999999999&0&98.770833333333357&1036.2833333333333&61.287499999999994&538.11666666666656&436.87916666666683&365&192&71&102&2645
010. Ourense, Spain &Spain&Ourense&2&1&21&2&1&21&1684.8125000000005&1513.8833333333339&0.40833333333333499&170.52083333333334&1087.6000000000001&9.0750000000000028&914.04583333333346&164.47916666666671&365&183&115&67&575
011. Leon, Spain &Spain&Leon&2&1&21&2&1&21&2749.7125000000001&2609.9041666666667&8.9000000000000092&130.90833333333336&625.66666666666674&3.7916666666666714&442.7833333333333&179.0916666666667&365&236&67&62&0
012. San Sebastian, Spain &Spain&San Sebastian&2&2&22&2&1&21&1909.3125&1773.2791666666667&0.34166666666666501&135.69166666666658&694.02916666666647&36.187499999999986&292.95416666666659&364.88749999999993&365&224&42&99&1743
013. Valladolid, Spain &Spain&Valladolid&2&1&21&2&1&21&2376.6249999999991&2302.9999999999991&0.61250000000000426&73.012500000000017&892.3&18.25&761.66250000000002&112.38749999999999&365&229&99&37&0
```

Comment: For internal description of the table you don't need those keys. Why can't you load the files?

Comment: I have added the error message to the question.

Comment: Is it true that the row numbers are different on line 11? Looks like this might be a row sep problem if it is not.

Comment: No, to my eyes there it the same number of columns (also excel agrees). I have included the first few rows of my data above. Also if I use `\pgfplotstabletypeset[some options]{\CCData/results/1318AaBb-1day.txt}` directly it works.

Answer (score 2):

I can replicate this behavior. And I don't know why but I suspect there is some Unicode problem lurking somewhere.

I couldn't find what the offending characters are but if I import your data to Excel and export back again it starts reading the table with no problem. Then I also used `filecontents` environment by copy pasting your data. Didn't work but if I overwrite the file with some legitimate input and then import your data after sanitizing it works again.

So my bet is on your data encoding or something related.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,filecontents,pdflscape}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
{001. Porto, Portugal     } & Portugal & Porto         & 4 & 2 & 42 & 4 & 1 & 41 & 1491.6666666666674 & 1291.7916666666674  & 2.4958333333333336  & 197.37916666666663   & 882.76250000000005 &  31.149999999999991  &  485.70416666666665  &  365.90833333333336  & 365 & 184 & 69  & 112 & 2106
{002. Braganca, Portugal  } & Portugal & Bragança      & 2 & 1 & 21 & 2 & 1 & 21 & 2339.974999999999  & 2207.4624999999992  & 0.28333333333333854 & 132.22916666666671   & 893.21249999999998 &  13.983333333333352  &  700.82083333333333  &  178.40833333333333  & 365 & 222 & 81  & 62  & 152 
{003. Coimbra, Portugal   } & Portugal & Coimbra       & 4 & 2 & 42 & 4 & 2 & 42 & 1294.3124999999998 & 1155.1208333333332  & 3.6291666666666664  & 135.5625             & 1209.1083333333333 &  27.895833333333329  &  943.25416666666672  &  237.95833333333326  & 365 & 166 & 125 & 74  & 2532
{004. Lisbon, Portugal    } & Portugal & Lisbon        & 4 & 2 & 42 & 4 & 2 & 42 & 1086.0833333333335 & 964.28333333333353  & 2.3333333333333393  & 119.46666666666668   & 1443.9624999999996 & 21.954166666666637   & 1219.7791666666662   & 202.22916666666666   & 365 & 151 & 150 & 64  & 2394 
{005. La Coruna, Spain    } & Spain    & La Coruña     & 4 & 2 & 42 & 4 & 1 & 41 & 1487.9537500000001 & 1360.1995833333335  & 0                   & 127.75416666666669   & 764.72916666666674 & 58.320833333333283   & 269.34999999999997   & 437.05833333333351   & 365 & 214 & 41  & 110 & 1613 
{006. Pontevedra, Spain   } & Spain    & Pontevedra    & 4 & 1 & 41 & 4 & 1 & 41 & 1328.2791666666665 & 1212.5999999999999  & 0                   & 115.67916666666666   & 1062.6833333333332 & 50.558333333333323   & 598.98749999999984   & 413.1375000000001    & 365 & 186 & 77  & 102 & 709  
{007. Lugo, Spain         } & Spain    & Lugo          & 2 & 1 & 21 & 1 & 1 & 11 & 2496.2333333333318 & 2317.1583333333315  & 3.2666666666666622  & 175.80833333333331   & 446.71666666666658 & 11.90833333333334    & 140.33333333333337   & 294.47499999999991   & 365 & 247 & 24  & 94  & 320  
{008. Oviedo, Spain       } & Spain    & Oviedo        & 2 & 1 & 21 & 1 & 1 & 11 & 2018.7999999999986 & 1882.108333333332   & 0                   & 136.69166666666666   & 587.9041666666667  & 30.062499999999986   & 247.41250000000002   & 310.42916666666667   & 365 & 237 & 39  & 89  & 958  
{009. Santander, Spain    } & Spain    & Santander     & 4 & 2 & 42 & 4 & 2 & 42 & 1368.9958333333332 & 1270.2249999999999  & 0                   & 98.770833333333357   & 1036.2833333333333 & 61.287499999999994   & 538.11666666666656   & 436.87916666666683   & 365 & 192 & 71  & 102 & 2645 
{010. Ourense, Spain      } & Spain    & Ourense       & 2 & 1 & 21 & 2 & 1 & 21 & 1684.8125000000005 & 1513.8833333333339  & 0.40833333333333499 & 170.52083333333334   & 1087.6000000000001 & 9.0750000000000028   & 914.04583333333346   & 164.47916666666671   & 365 & 183 & 115 & 67  & 575  
{011. Leon, Spain         } & Spain    & Leon          & 2 & 1 & 21 & 2 & 1 & 21 & 2749.7125000000001 & 2609.9041666666667  & 8.9000000000000092  & 130.90833333333336   & 625.66666666666674 & 3.7916666666666714   & 442.7833333333333    & 179.0916666666667    & 365 & 236 & 67  & 62  & 0    
{012. San Sebastian, Spain} & Spain    & San Sebastian & 2 & 2 & 22 & 2 & 1 & 21 & 1909.3125          & 1773.2791666666667  & 0.34166666666666501 & 135.69166666666658   & 694.02916666666647 & 36.187499999999986   & 292.95416666666659   & 364.88749999999993   & 365 & 224 & 42  & 99  & 1743 
{013. Valladolid, Spain   } & Spain    & Valladolid    & 2 & 1 & 21 & 2 & 1 & 21 & 2376.6249999999991 & 2302.9999999999991  & 0.61250000000000426 & 73.012500000000017   & 892.3              & 18.25                & 761.66250000000002   & 112.38749999999999   & 365 & 229 & 99  & 37  & 0    
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=&,header=false]{data.csv}{\mytable}

\begin{document}
\tiny
\begin{landscape}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[every head row/.style={output empty row},
column type=r,
display columns/0/.style={string type},
display columns/1/.style={string type},
display columns/2/.style={string type}
]{\mytable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That does not sound to good. My original data are a bunch of xlsx files I have converted to txt using xlsx2csv so I am a bit confused how getting it back to excel and then txt helps. How did you do the export from excel? Just save/export as .csv? Could that be automated? (the only way I found was xlsx2csv).

Comment: @MatoBehr You have something weird going on with your charset probably.

Comment: I have tried to check and with `file -I filename` my mac told me that the files was utf-8 encoded. (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539294/how-do-i-determine-file-encoding-in-osx)

Comment: How did you "sanitise" the data?

Comment: @MatoBehr Can you delete all aux etc. files and copy paste my code and compile it?

Comment: Yes and no. I was able to compile your code but only after commenting out `\usepackage{fontspec}` and `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}`.

Comment: Can you see ñ in Coruña without it (are you using inputenc)? Your `pgfplots` package is then outdated. Better update that too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18429/discussion-between-matobehr-and-percusse).